# What does 都 mean when added to 主 here: 主都知道，主都不在乎

Tags: word, word-order

This is a quote from “黑暗森林”， I've never quite understood the 都 there. Also, I've opened the book and tried a quick search, it seems like the author switches between 主都 and 主, which is entirely out of my HSK1 undertsanding.

Comment: 主 means 'God'.  The sentence reads as xxx 都知道.  The same as 我都知道.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

都 (dou1) means "all" here. It is a separate word with 主, and its meaning unrelated to 主.

主都知道：主 knows all.

主都不在乎：主 does not care about anything.

Comment: 都 has to be preceded by a plural noun phrase, so the sentence implies that all gods know, rather than gods know all. And all gods don't care

Comment: @小奥利奥 No, this is a different use case as ”他们都知道“, which means "all of them know". Actually "他们都知道” is ambiguous as it can also be interpreted as "they know all". (都 has yet another interpretation, making all of them ambiguous ...）

Comment: The other interpretaion is "even": Even they know.

Answer (score 1):

> 主 lord

> 都 all (positive), any (negative)

> 知道 know

> 不 not

> 在乎 care

主都知道 The Lord knows all.

主都不在乎 The Lord doesn't care any.